# Applying function to different combinations of the arguments in R

Tags: r, for-loop, mapply

I have two variables (one independent and one dependent), containing 5 data points each, which I have created a `function (x,y)` to fit different models to them. This is working quite nice. However, the problem is that I also need to apply this same function to different combinations of these data points. In other words, I need to apply the function using the different combinations of using only 4, 3, and 2 data points. In total, there are 25 possible combinations. I was wondering what would be the most efficient way of doing it?

Please, see below an example of my data:

```
tte <- c(100,172,434,857,1361) #dependent variable
po <- c(446,385,324,290,280) #independent variable

Results <- myFunction (tte=tte, po=po) # customized function
```

Below is an example of how I am getting all the possible combinations using 4 data points:

```
tte4 <- combn(tte,4)
po4 <- combn(po,4)
```

Please, note that the first column of `tte4` has always to be analyzed with the first column of `po4`. Then, the second column of `tte4` with the second column of `po4` and so on. What I need to do is to use `myFunction` on all these combinations.

I have tried to implement it through a `for loop` and through `mapply` without much success.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the *simplify=FALSE* argument of `combn`, then pass the list of vectors with `mapply` (or its wrapper `Map`).

```
tte_list <- combn(tte,4, simplify = FALSE)
po_list <- combn(po, 4, simplify = FALSE)

# MATRIX OR VECTOR RETURN
res_matrix <- mapply(myFunction, tte_list, po_list)

# LIST RETURN
res_list <- Map(myFunction, tte_list, po_list)
```

Comment: Dear @Parfait, this is amazing! Thank you very much for your reply! The code is working great! I wasn't aware of the `Map` function. I have implemented it now!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I meant to tag is as useful, but as I am new here StackOverflow doesn't show it. I also accepted it now.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what function you want to perform, I just summed the columns.  This function takes three arguments:

index = A sequence of 1 to how many columns there are in tte4 (should be same as po4)

x = tte4

y = po4.

Then it should use that index on both matrices to ID the columns you want.  And in this case, I summed them.

```
tte <- c(100,172,434,857,1361) #dependent variable
po <- c(446,385,324,290,280) #independent variable

results <- function(index, x, y){
  i.x <- x[,index]
  i.y <- y[,index]
  sum(i.x) + sum(i.y)
}

tte4 <- combn(tte, 4)
po4 <- combn(po,4)

index <- 1:ncol(tte4)

sapply(index, results, x = tte4, y = po4)
#[1] 3008 3502 3891 4092 4103
```

Comment: That worked great! Thank you very much for the reply!